# Ubuntu 16.04 on HP Envy 15 latptop doesn't boot (AMD A10)

Tags: boot, 16.04, hp, amd-graphics, amd-processor

Ubuntu 16.04 successfully boots from USB flash drive, no errors during installation to HDD, but after the installation finishes, booting freezes after a few seconds. Sometimes screen blinks during that freeze, sometimes CPU starts overheating.

I already tried the following:

1. Disabled/enabled secure boot
2. Disabled ACPI in Grub
3. Used different USB drives and disk images
4. Ran memory diagnostic tool that didn't found any problems
5. Tried to boot in recovery and got "General protection fault" error

Unfortunately, nothing helped to boot. Could someone help me?

P.S. Windows works fine on this laptop.

Comment: 04.01 (not 02 !!!) it helped me with same issue
https://askubuntu.com/questions/916348/hp-laptop-amd-apu-fail-to-boot-live-linux-cd

Comment: Try ubuntu 16.04.01 LTS (not 02 !!!) it helped me with same issue
https://askubuntu.com/questions/916348/hp-laptop-amd-apu-fail-to-boot-live-linux-cd