# HP Laptop AMD APU - Fail to Boot - Live linux cd

Tags: live-usb, amd-graphics, amd-processor

Hi i am having a problem with booting HP Laptop into live Ubuntu CD/USB

### HP laptop 15-ba062nc

- AMD A10-9600P
- Integrated GPU:  R5
- Secondary  GPU:  R7 M440

I tried booting several live distros:

- ubuntu-mate-16.04.2-desktop-amd64
- kubuntu-14.04.5-desktop-amd64
- ubuntu-mate-17.04-desktop-amd64
- antergos-17.5-x86_64

Secure boot disabled, tried enabling/disabling virtualisation, Legacy/UEFI switching with all distros but nothing helped.

During booting of live cds some things might change across the different distros. But with Ubuntu based distros it repeats attempts to initiate this:

```
AMD-Vi: Completion-Wait loop timed out
AMD-Vi: Event logged [
```

Here is the end screen

[image]

UPDATE: Consider it Solved.
After successful installation of version 16.04.01 system got updated to 16.04.02 LTS Without a problem.
Hope it helps to anybody with similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

At startup you have to give the parameter "amd_iommu=off".To have it permanently incorporate it into your grub config.

Comment: nothing unfortunatelly

Answer (score 0):

Please try patch from.
https://patchwork.freedesktop.org/patch/157327/
It should be in mainline soon.

Comment: I think the link is the patch and the patch is the answer. But raja, please mention how to apply the patch. I suppose you could include it in the answer as well...

Comment: I would love to, but like Zanna said.