# Installation of Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS Error AMD Graphics Card

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation, amd-graphics

I want to install Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS on my HP Pavilion 15-AW009AX (256 GB SSD, 16GB RAM, AMD Radeon R7 M440 and an AMD 9600P Processor).

I followed the installation guidelines to install Ubuntu via a bootable USB flash drive and chose to "Install Ubuntu". The screen froze upon installation and after browsing through a few forums I found that replacing "quiet splash" with "nomodeset" within the "Install Ubuntu" command may be able to solve my problem. Ubuntu installed, however, I got stuck in a loop when logging in - the screen would basically go blank and then take me back to the login screen.

I then rebooted and loaded the GRUB terminal, entering the "Ubuntu" menu I added "radeon.modeset=0" to the end of the line starting with "linux" as my HP has an AMD graphics card and upon reboot I am getting the following error screen:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWbRB.jpg]

I have been through a few forums and I believe I am having problems due to the graphics card. If anyone could help I would really appreciate it.

**EDIT**

I have found another post on the ask ubuntu forums which lists a similar issue encountered when trying to boot ubuntu onto a HP laptop with similar specs: [HP Laptop AMD APU - Fail to Boot - Live linux cd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/916348/hp-laptop-amd-apu-fail-to-boot-live-linux-cd?answertab=active#tab-top)

The post mentioned above conatins a link to a patch which I believe may solve the issue. I am unsure how to go about applying the patch. Will I be required to patch and compile the source code for the kernal?

**EDIT**

Running `fsck -y /dev/sda2`at the initramfs prompt returns the following:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk0RF.jpg]

The AMD-Vi: Completion-Wait loop timed out appears to be addressed in the patch mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the **BusyBox** screen by manually fixing the filesystem with this at the prompt:

```
(initramfs) fsck -y /dev/sda2
```

*(In the above command, the initramfs is the prompt you're seeing.  The text the follows is the command to type in.)*

Fix the graphics problem by running this at a console prompt.  First boot using the **nomodeset** grub parameter.  You can get to a console by hitting this keyboard short cut: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl></kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

**Install Graphic Drivers from Commandline**

Run this command to show the available drivers for your GPU:

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
```

You'll be safer by picking the one that the system identifies as **recommended**.

To install a driver from the list run this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install [drivername]
```

To see which driver is currently in use (most likely the one that is failing) run:

```
$ sudo lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3
```

Comment: You're very welcome.  Did you test the steps?  I'm sure it'll resolve your issue.  If it fails, I would like to know the type of error you get so that I can fix the answer and help with your resolution.

Comment: I ran the fsck command at the initramfs prompt as directed. This ended with a series of five lines of the form: [   XX.XXXXXX] AMD-Vi: Completion-Wait loop timed out. This is what was appearing after several attempts at logging in. I believe this issue is addressed in the patch mentioned in the EDIT above.

Comment: There are a number of ways to fix problems.  Personally, I would try first using the default Operating system which usually works.  The link in your question is different from the Busybox prompt that you have, with is very specifically a problem (separate from the Graphics card issue) to the integrity of your file system... partially `/dev/sda2`.  That would have to be addressed before going further.  It's very important not to interrupt the `fsck` program.  If you don't interrupt it.  It should fix that part of your problem.  Are you still getting the same **fix `/dev/sda` filesystem?**

Comment: As shown in the edit above running the `fsck` program appears to modify `/dev/sda2` file system. This is then followed by the AMD-Vi: Completion-Wait loop timed out issue.

Comment: Sorry.  I didn't notice you had updated the question.  I'll study the update and provide a resolution for the new screen... if you don't mind.  The new screen is different.  It appears to have cleaned the `/dev/sda` problem.